# I can't create a form with password1 password2 in Django

Tags: python, django

error:Unknown field(s) (password1, password2) specified for User

I have no idea why it doesn't work as documentation says

Documentation:

```
class UserCreationForm¶
A ModelForm for creating a new user.

It has three fields: username (from the user model), password1, and password2. 
It verifies that password1 and password2 match, validates the password using validate_password(), 
and sets the user’s password using set_password().
```

My forms.py

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
   class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

my views.py

```
class CreateUserView(CreateView):
   model = User
   form = CreateUserForm
   template_name = 'registration/register.html'
   fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2 ]


class UserLoginView(LoginView):
   next_page = "home.html"
']
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', CreateUserView.as_view(), name='register'),


]
```

Comment: `password1` and `password2` are *not* fields of the `User`. You should remove these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`password1` and `password2` are *not* fields of the `User`. You should remove these:

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
   class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
       model = User
       fields = ['username', 'email']
```

but with this, it makes not much sense to inherit the form anyway.

Furthermore you specify the form class with [**`form_class`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_class), not `form`, so:

```
class CreateUserView(CreateView):
   model = User
   form_class = CreateUserForm
   template_name = 'registration/register.html'
```

Comment: Thank you it works now. Could you explain why my CBV shouldn't have a fields variable?

Comment: @HubertBudny: you specify `fields`, if you do not specify the `form_class`. In that case the `CreateView` (or `UpdateView`) will construct a model form class with the given model and fields. But here you *did* specify a `form_class`, hence the `fields` will be ignored.